# Not able to fetch attribute from api response

Tags: postman

I am trying to fetch the error message from the api response, but it is showing me error at [ saying "Identifier expected" in the test case in line 3. I am thinking it needs to be escaped but i am not sure how to do that there. Response message is below:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "[0].roomTemp[0].Value": [
            "The field Value must be between 0 and 99.98999786376953."
        ]
    },
   "status": 400,
}
```

Test case written is below :

```
pm.test("Validate Error Message to be : The field Value must be between 0 and 99.98999786376953.", function () {
    var responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(responseJson.errors.[0].roomTemp[0].Value).to.eql(pm.globals.get("Id"));
});
```

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo. It tells you that you got a `[` when it expected an identifier: `object.propertyName` has to have a property name after the dot. You can't put a square bracket there. Don't mix up dot notation and square bracket notation.

Comment: I dont agree to what you have said. Its not a typo, that is how a the response is returned for that api and i am facing issues with fetching the error message. However i know the information that object.propertyName has to have a property name after the dot. but i am not sure in above scenario how i can fetch the error message. Please help me in this, if you are not aware of the answer then please remove the -ve voting and let others who know reply it.

Comment: Here is the solution i found for it.  pm.expect(responseJson.errors["[0].roomTemp[0].Value"][0]).to.eql(pm.globals.get("Id"));